# Java equivalent of python nested for loop

Tags: java, python, python-3.x

Say we had the following python nested loop:

```
for i in range(0, len(A)):
  for k in range(i, len(A)):
     # Do something
```

What would be the java equivalent? This is what I got:

```
for (int i = 0; i < A.length ; i ++) {
  int j = i;
  for (j ; j < A.length ; j++) {
     // Do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks right to me, although you can declare j in the for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j < number; j++) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

For the sake of completeness, python loops of this form:

```
for item in sequence:
    #do something
```

can be done in java as follows:

```
for (type item : sequence) {  //type being the type of the items in the sequence
    //do something
}
```

Comment: I tried this but I got the following error:  Syntax error on token "j", ++ expected after this token

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put 'int' before j.